# Create an RDD of FileMetadata

Tags: apache-spark

We have files with naming convention as below. Each file size if few KBs and we have millions of them in NFS.

> "XXXXXXXXXX..YYMMDD.HHMMSS.NNNN.tarbz2

We want to load only last 5 files per month per "XXXXXXXXXX".

We can do Filesystem calls to get the filenames and give a filtered set of files to sc.binaryFiles. But this seems hack and may not work once we move to HDFS!!!

Is there a better way of achieving this usecase in spark?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example for the file names and how one can identify the files to load?

Comment: you can try using `wholeTextFiles()` method od sparkContext it will return the tuplefor `[(FileName, fileContent)]` you can filter according to this

Comment: @AkashSethi As I mentioned the files are binary, loading with wholeTextFile will not be right.

Comment: @hage Files are sorted based on "YYMMDD.HHMMSS.NNNN" as mentioned in the filename and latest 5 files are taken.